# How can you disable the network connection in a Flutter Test?

Tags: flutter, testing

I am making a call to a web server with the http package and I want to test this functionality when there is no internet connection. Is there a way to disable the connectivity in a test? Or should I mock the http package?

Answer (score 1):

You can mock the channel of connectivity like this
@user6288393 @Mau Di Bert

```
  const MethodChannel channel =
  MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/connectivity');

  channel.setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
    return ConnectivityResult.none;
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, the easiest way to do that is to edit the emulator configuration. If you are running Android, that's where you find this config. You can change **Signal strength** to **none**. If you are running an iOS emulator, in the settings there should be a similar config.

I hope that helps

[image: Android Emulator signal configuration]

Comment: I am talking about testing with unit tests, not in the emulator. But this is nevertheless interesting to know.

Comment: Did you find a solution doing unit tests?